# How to interpret R's auto.arima function alongside the ACF and PACF?

Tags: time-series, arima

I have annual time series data for rice productivity for India from 1951 through 2008.

I stored the data as a **ts** object in R and made the data stationary with one difference as indicated by

```
> ndiffs(rice)
[1] 1
```

My ACF and PACF for the first difference of the logarithm of the rice series `log(rice)` look like so:

[image]
[image]

Observing the ACF and PACF indicates an ARIMA(2,1,1) process, but the `auto.arima()` function in R indicates an ARIMA(0,1,1) process. Has this got to do with the principle of parsimony? I'm not sure. Can someone please help me identify my model correctly?

```
> auto.arima(log(rice))
Series: log(rice) 
ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         

Coefficients:
          ma1   drift
      -0.7650  0.0191
s.e.   0.1115  0.0026

sigma^2 estimated as 0.006048:  log likelihood=64.13
AIC=-122.27   AICc=-121.82   BIC=-116.14
```

Answer (score 1):

If the production data is from [here](http://www.airea.net/page/62/statistical-data/all-india-area-production-and-yield-of-rice), why are you taking logs?  Are you adjusting for outliers? 2002 has a huge outlier.  Are you adjusting for that?

A first difference model with an AR1 with two outliers would work very well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even if I don't take a log transform of the series, I get the same ACF and PACF. My motivation for a log was to model productivity growth, since a first difference of log ~ percentage change. The issue is how to determine an appropriate model from the ACF and PACFplots. In particular, why not an ARIMA(2,1,1) ?

Comment: George Box said "all models are wrong, but some are useful". What are you doing about the outliers??  They impact the ACF/PACF.